# Successful build but process exited with status 1, deploying rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have been getting the following errors after the build has been successful. Any ideas on how to fix this error?

> 2019-02-24T23:51:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user timdom11@gmail.com 
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:41.818679+00:00 app[api]: Release v16 created by user timdom11@gmail.com
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:41.818679+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2096254f by user timdom11@gmail.com 
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:42.540367+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:44.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:48.259082+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>    command `bin/rails server -p 23822 -e production`
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.313462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>    starting to crashed 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221432+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:76:in
>    `block in load_missing_constant`: uninitialized constant Knock
>    (NameError) 
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221452+00:00 app[web.1]: from
>    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in
>    `without_bootsnap_cache` 
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221697+00:00 app[web.1]: from
>    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:76:in
>    `rescue in load_missing_constant` 
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221700+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in
>    `load_missing_constant` 
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221702+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/user_token_controller.rb:1:in `<main>`
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221704+00:00 app[web.1]: from
>    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in
>    `require` 
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221706+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in
>    `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221842+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221844+00:00 app[web.1]: from
>    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi` 
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221846+00:00 app[web.1]: from
>    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in
>   `require`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221848+00:00 app[web.1]: from
>    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in
>   `block in loading`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221850+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in
>   `exclusive` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221858+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in
>   `loading`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221860+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in
>   `block in require_or_load`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221862+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in
>   `allow_bootsnap_retry`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221863+00:00 app[web.1]:
>     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in
>   `require_or_load`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221865+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:82:in
>   `depend_on`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221866+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in
>   `block (2 levels) in eager_load!` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221868+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in
>   `each`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221870+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in
>   `block in eager_load!`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221923+00:00 app[web.1]:
>     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in
>   `each`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221926+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in
>   `eager_load!` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221927+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in
>   `eager_load!`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221929+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in
>   `each` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in
>   `block in <module:Finisher>` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221932+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
>   `instance_exec`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221933+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
>   `run` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221935+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in
>   `block in run_initializers`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221936+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in
>   tsort_each`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221938+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2
>   levels) in each_strongly_connected_component`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in
>   `each_strongly_connected_component_from`
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221941+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in
>   each_strongly_connected_component`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221943+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each`
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221944+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call`
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221950+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in
>   `each_strongly_connected_component`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221952+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each`
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221954+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each`
>   
>  2019-02-24T23:51:53.221955+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in
>   `run_initializers`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in
>   `initialize!`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221959+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221960+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in
>   `require`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221963+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in
>   `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221965+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in
>   `register` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221966+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in
>   `require_with_bootsnap_lfi`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221974+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in
>   `require`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in
>   `require_relative`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221977+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   config.ru:3:in `block in <main>`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221979+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in
>   `instance_eval`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221981+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in
>   `initialize`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221983+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   config.ru:in `new`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221984+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   config.ru:in `<main>` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221986+00:00 app[web.1]:
>     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in
>   `eval`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221988+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in
>   `new_from_string`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221989+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in
>   `parse_file`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in
>   `build_app_and_options_from_config`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221993+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in
>   `app` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221994+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in
>   `app`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221996+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in
>   `wrapped_app`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221997+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in
>   `start`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.221999+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in
>   `start`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in
>   `block in perform`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in
>   `tap`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222004+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in
>   `perform`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222005+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
>   `run` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222007+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in
>   `invoke_command`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222009+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in
>   `dispatch` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222010+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in
>   `perform`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222012+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in
>   `invoke` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222014+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in
>   `<main>`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222015+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in
>   `require`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222017+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in
>   `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222018+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in
>   `register`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222020+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in
>   `require_with_bootsnap_lfi`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222022+00:00
>    app[web.1]:    from
>    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require` 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.222023+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>`
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.223670+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.223672+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.2 application starting in production
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.223673+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h`
>   for more startup options 
>   
> 2019-02-24T23:51:53.223675+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting 2019-02-24T23:51:53.294763+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

Comment: The following errors when loading the page:
2019-02-24T23:47:53.992508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=existentialeconomics.herokuapp.com request_id=09b61985-1abe-4768-815b-7bdfc6365e56 fwd="196.61.107.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-02-24T23:47:55.296178+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=existentialeconomics.herokuapp.com request_id=27d73df4-aea6-4de7-b835-58fdff3ae1a0 fwd="196.61.107.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The authentication method I was causing the crash. After fixing this the website ran perfectly.